# Include JS scripts (JQuery-UI) in the right order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to optimize things and include only the things actually used (dialogs and tabs).

Here's what works :

```
<script src="/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

NB the minified versions work too.

JQuery has [a nice documentation about how to use it with various packages managers](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/bower/) such as Bower or AMD to include only the libs that you need, but it doesn't go into details.

My idea was to include every separate script, and then start taking out what we don't need. The only clue as to the order, I found in a comment at the top the full JQuery-UI lib, that says:

```
/*! jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2016-09-14
* http://jqueryui.com
* Includes: widget.js, position.js, data.js, disable-selection.js, effect.js, effects/effect-blind.js, effects/effect-bounce.js, effects/effect-clip.js, effects/effect-drop.js, effects/effect-explode.js, effects/effect-fade.js, effects/effect-fold.js, effects/effect-highlight.js, effects/effect-puff.js, effects/effect-pulsate.js, effects/effect-scale.js, effects/effect-shake.js, effects/effect-size.js, effects/effect-slide.js, effects/effect-transfer.js, focusable.js, form-reset-mixin.js, jquery-1-7.js, keycode.js, labels.js, scroll-parent.js, tabbable.js, unique-id.js, widgets/accordion.js, widgets/autocomplete.js, widgets/button.js, widgets/checkboxradio.js, widgets/controlgroup.js, widgets/datepicker.js, widgets/dialog.js, widgets/draggable.js, widgets/droppable.js, widgets/menu.js, widgets/mouse.js, widgets/progressbar.js, widgets/resizable.js, widgets/selectable.js, widgets/selectmenu.js, widgets/slider.js, widgets/sortable.js, widgets/spinner.js, widgets/tabs.js, widgets/tooltip.js
* Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors; Licensed MIT */
```

So I included them in this very order:

```
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/core.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/position.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/data.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/disable-selection.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effect.js"></script>

<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/"></script>

<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-blind.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-bounce.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-clip.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-drop.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-explode.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-fade.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-fold.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-highlight.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-puff.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-pulsate.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-scale.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-shake.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-size.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-slide.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-transfer.js"></script>


<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/focusable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/form-reset-mixin.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/keycode.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/labels.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/scroll-parent.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/tabbable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/unique-id.js"></script>


<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/accordion.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/accordion.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/button.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/checkboxradio.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/controlgroup.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/menu.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/progressbar.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/resizable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/resizable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectmenu.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/spinner.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tabs.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tooltip.js"></script>
```

But it fails violently:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    jQuery 2 core.js:3:1
```

If there is any documentation about how to include JQuery-UI libs separately, thank you very much for pointing me to it.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/download/ (And IMO - Try using newer libraries, jQueryUI is OLD!)

Comment: Yes, I know about the DLoad service, but I need to use Bower ; As for JQuery, at the time of creating the site it was the *only* viable drag & drop implementation, and AFAIK it sadly still is :/

Comment: [Read here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/main/ui/core.js): _// This file is deprecated in 1.12.0 to be removed in 1.13_ So maybe try to remove this file `<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/core.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out the proper order, as well as some things that have to be removed altogether for everything to work.

The core.js lib gives indications:

```
# cat ui/core.js
// This file is deprecated in 1.12.0 to be removed in 1.13
...
```

NB The file `jquery-1-7.js` is **not** JQuery, but a back-compat lib :/

So, here is what I have now:

```
<script src="/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
-->

<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/core.js"></script>
-->

<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/version.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/data.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/disable-selection.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/focusable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/form.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/ie.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/keycode.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/labels.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-1-7.js"></script> -->
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/plugin.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/safe-active-element.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/safe-blur.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/scroll-parent.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/tabbable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/unique-id.js"></script>


<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/position.js"></script>

<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/form-reset-mixin.js"></script>

<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effect.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-blind.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-bounce.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-clip.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-drop.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-explode.js"></script> -->
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-fade.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-fold.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-highlight.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-puff.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-pulsate.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-scale.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-shake.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-size.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-slide.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-transfer.js"></script>
-->
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/accordion.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js"></script> -->
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/button.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/checkboxradio.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/controlgroup.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js"></script> -->
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog.js"></script>

<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/menu.js"></script> -->
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/progressbar.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/resizable.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectable.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectmenu.js"></script> -->
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/spinner.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tabs.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tooltip.js"></script> -->
<script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js"></script>
<!--
     <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/escape-selector.js"></script>
     <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/form.js"></script>
     <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/ie.js"></script>
     <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/plugin.js"></script>
     <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/safe-active-element.js"></script>
     <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/safe-blur.js"></script>
     <script src="/bower/jquery-ui/ui/version.js"></script>
-->
```